# Paged-based iPhone application - using functions from RootViewController in DataViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm building a page-based iPhone app with Storyboards and ARC. I'm trying to use a function in the RootViewController class to flip to a particular page from inside a function in the DataViewController class.

The issue is that the main instance of the DataViewController class is not found inside the RootViewController class -- but its found inside the ModelController class. And it seems that the ModelController class is read-only (so I cannot set the delegate for the ModelController from outside classes such as the RootViewController class)

My initial plan was to:

**1) Set the ModelController delegate to the RootViewController from the RootViewController class**

**2) Set the DataViewController delegate to the ModelController's delegate**

But that does not seem to be working - I'm assuming due to the read-only-ness of the ModelController class...

How can I use the function in the RootViewController class from the DataViewController class in this case? Is there a better way to accomplish this rather than setting delegates?

Comment: Just got it to work by doing: 

RootViewController *rvc = (RootViewController *)self.parentViewController.parentViewController;

[rvc functionToDo];

Not sure if this is the best way to do it but it works for now

Answer (score 2):

The way I did this was by using a notification

I added a notification on the button click in the DataViewController

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"H2RAutoPage" object:nil];
```

And in the RootViewController in the viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(autoPage:) name:@"H2RAutoPage" object:nil];
```

My AutoPage Routine looks like this

```
- (void)autoPage: (NSNotification *)notification
{
//get current index of current page
 NSUInteger currentPage = [self.modelController indexOfViewController:    [self.pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]];
// this is the next page nil mean we have reach the end
H2RDataViewController *targetPageViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:(currentPage + 1) storyboard:self.storyboard];

if (targetPageViewController) {
    //put it(or them if in landscape view) in an array
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:targetPageViewController, nil];
    //add page view
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

}

I did also try use a delegate but found the code was becoming messy since It kept losing the  delegate I found NSnotification much cleaner.