# Go to a page of a UIPageViewController from a DataViewController?

Tags: xcode

I am using the page based application template from xcode that creates a RootViewController, a DataViewController and a ModelController.

I have managed to make it go to what ever page I need, from the RootViewController, but I also need this from the DataViewController, triggered on an event from a specific page. That does not work so well. How should I change the code for it to work from DataViewController?

My code looks like this:
-from root(working):

```
//get current index of current page
DataViewController *theCurrentViewController = [self.pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
NSUInteger retreivedIndex = [self.modelController indexOfViewController:theCurrentViewController];

//get the page(s) to go to
DataViewController *targetPageViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:(pageToGoTo - 1) storyboard:self.storyboard];

//put it(or them if in landscape view) in an array
NSArray *theViewControllers = nil;
theViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:targetPageViewController, nil];

//check which direction to animate page turn then turn page accordingly
if (retreivedIndex < (pageToGoTo - 1) && retreivedIndex != (pageToGoTo - 1)){
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:theViewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL]; 
} 
if (retreivedIndex > (pageToGoTo - 1) && retreivedIndex != (pageToGoTo - 1)){
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:theViewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

-from a page, dataviewcontroller(not working):

```
DataViewController *targetPageViewController = [((UIPageViewController*)self.parentViewController) viewControllerAtIndex:(pageToGoTo - 1) storyboard:self.storyboard]; //The problem is here, but I do not know how to solve it.


//put it(or them if in landscape view) in an array
NSArray *theViewControllers = nil;
theViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:targetPageViewController, nil];


[((UIPageViewController*)self.parentViewController) setViewControllers: theViewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered this question here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16435166/1463518

The way I did this was by using a notification

I added a notification on the button click in the DataViewController

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"H2RAutoPage" object:nil];
```

And in the RootViewController in the viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(autoPage:) name:@"H2RAutoPage" object:nil];
```

My AutoPage Routine looks like this

```
- (void)autoPage: (NSNotification *)notification
{
//get current index of current page
  NSUInteger currentPage = [self.modelController indexOfViewController:[self.pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]];
// this is the next page nil mean we have reach the end
  H2RDataViewController *targetPageViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:(currentPage + 1) storyboard:self.storyboard];
  if (targetPageViewController) {
      //put it(or them if in landscape view) in an array
       NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:targetPageViewController, nil];
      //add page view
      [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];
  }

}
```

I did also try use a delegate but found the code was becoming messy since It kept losing the delegate I found NSnotification much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a delegate. Did not know what that was at the time of writing. I guess this solution could work also.